# Stack corrupted only for debug configuration C++

Tags: c++, registry, stack-corruption

I'm trying to get a version of some program through registry. My code works fine when set on release configuration. When I try to run it in debug mode, my code crashes when leaving this function with message "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'version' was corrupted".

I will paste only relevant code of my function. That's all of "version" appearances in my code. When I debug it, version gets proper value. Code doesn't crash in release configuration. For both of configuration I set "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".

```
TCHAR version[20];
DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
if (RegQueryValueEx(hAppKey, "DisplayVersion", NULL,&dwType, (unsigned char*)version, &dwBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{
    dwBufferSize = 20;
    std::string vers(version, dwBufferSize);
    return vers;
}
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does *not* work fine in release. It contains a buffer overrun which is what the debug build, which contains additional error checking, is picking up on.

A cursory glance [at the documentation for RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.120).aspx) shows what you are doing is wrong:

`LONG WINAPI RegQueryValueEx(
  _In_         HKEY hKey,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpValueName,
  _Reserved_   LPDWORD lpReserved,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpType,
  _Out_opt_    LPBYTE lpData,
  _Inout_opt_  LPDWORD lpcbData
);`

> lpcbData [in, out, optional]
>   A pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. When the function returns, this variable contains the size of the data copied to lpData.

You are telling the function that your buffer is of size 0 when it is actually 20 * sizeof(TCHAR) bytes, not 0 and not 20.

Please be super careful whenever you have to deal with c-style strings. This looks like you are introducing a security vulnerability into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're telling it that your buffer size is zero. Why don't you say 20?

Comment: of course it's not all the code. it is set to 20. otherwise it wouldn't work for release config.

Comment: @IggyBrodevíć : Then you haven't shown us enough relevant code. As it stands the `DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;` followed by `RegQueryValueEx` is just plain wrong. If you are actually doing that and running it in Release it may just appear to be doing the right thing when in fact it is just plain wrong. If that is not what your code is doing you need to present code that actually represents your real issue.

Comment: Without seeing more relevant code. My best guess of your problem is this. In your real code you set dwBufferSize to a value larger than the sizeof(version) .I use sizeof() since TCHAR could be 1 or 2 bytes although you say you build with MBCS which would make it 20.The stack corruption suggests that you owerwrote the `version` buffer and wiped out the guard bits used to detect if the stack was corrupted.The other possibility is you left out other code that handles `version` that overwrote the buffer. Did you append a nul (\0)terminating character on the end of a maxed out buffer by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be wrong as it says your buffer is 0. But is is 20 TCHAR:

```
DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
```

Should probably be:

```
DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(version);
```

This is important because this is used to pass into `RegQueryValueEx` as the size of the `version` buffer. `RegQueryValueEx` just so happens to update that value when it returns with the number of bytes actually used.